# Изменения архитектуры БД

Tags: sql, hibernate

В проекте есть ентити, между которыми настроенные связи ManyToMany. Например, Menu и Place. В базе эти данные сохраняются в таблице place_has_menu:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И все бы хорошо, но только эти таблицы воообще не используются. Они просто числятся в базе, но когда нужно вытащить все меню, по какому-то плейсу, используют джойны, но к этой таблице не обращаются. 
Стоит ли в связи с этим изменить связи между ентити как ManyToOne, OneToMany и убрать эти таблицы из базы? И даже если изменить связи, как от этого изменится сама архитектура и надо будет ли для связей ManyToOne и OneToMany таблицы, как на скриншоте или это сбавит немного вес базы?

**Update1**:
Menu.class :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="menu")
public class Menu {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column
private Long id;

@JoinColumn(name="name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy="menus", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Place> places = new HashSet<Place>();
// getter setters
}
```

**Update2**
Возник еще такой вопрос. У меня есть метод, например:

```
public void addByForm(PlaceForm placeForm, MultipartFile multipartFile){

    Place place = new Place();
    PlaceType placeType = placeTypeDao.getById(placeForm.getTypeId());
    place.setName(placeForm.getName());
    place.setFile(fileService.saveFile(multipartFile, "place"));
    place.getPlaceTypes().add(placeType);
    placeType.getPlaces().add(place);
}
```

Если изменить связи между энтити это отразится на работе таких методов? Или добавления слэш удаления будет работать по тому самому принципу?

Comment: т.е. у вас в Menu есть ссылка на Place?

Comment: @zRrr обновил вопрос. И еще такой вопрос? Если изменить связи, будет ли это как-то влиять на сервисы добавления и удаления меню из какого-то одного Place'а?

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял вопрос, но попробую все-таки ответить. В первую очередь нужно понимать ту бизнес специфику, для которой проектируется данная БД. В одном случае для одних и тех же сущностей вполне возможно, что достаточно будет связи `Один ко Многим`, в другом только `Многие ко Многим`.

Относительно сущностей они всегда должны отражать реальное положение дел и если в БД по какой-то причине есть поле, таблица или еще что-то, что уже не используется - лучшее удалить это, дабы не вносить сумбур и бардак в проект.

Поэтому, прежде чем удалять таблицу задайте себе вопрос, а какое отношение в моем случае нужно мне между сущностями `Menu` и `Place`. После этого, ответ на вопрос "*удалять или оставить или изменить что-то еще*" будет очевиден.

Comment: я обновил вопрос, так как возник еще один нюанс

Comment: Опять же, смотря что и как вы поменяете. Возможно, поменяв отношения между сущностями будет все хорошо, а может и упадет где-то. В любом случае, при возникновении каких либо проблем вам никто не мешает подправить "проблемный код" с учетом текущих реалий.